# Upload all files from a local folder to S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a python method to sends one file that exists in a local folder to S3. I want modify the method to send all files that exist in the folder to S3.

My method is:

```py
import boto3
from boto3 import Session
from botocore.exceptions import NoCredentialsError


session_root = boto3.Session(region_name='eu-west-3', profile_name='my_profile')
s3_client = session_root.client('s3')

prefix_key = "S3_folder/"
local_path = "/home/local_folder/"
bucket_name = "bucket_S3"

def upload_to_aws(local_file, bucket, s3_file):
    try:
        s3_client.upload_file(local_file, bucket, s3_file)
        print("Upload Successful")
        return True
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("The file was not found")
        return False
    except NoCredentialsError:
        print("Credentials not available")
        return False


uploaded_files_to_S3 = upload_to_aws(local_path, bucket_name, prefix_key)
```

To you have please an idea how can I modify it to take all files in my `local_folder` and send them to `S3_folder` ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `upload_file()` API call **can only upload one file at a time**.

Therefore, you will **need to loop through your directory** and upload each file individually:

```py
import os
import boto3

prefix_key = "S3_folder/"
local_path = "/home/local_folder/"
bucket_name = "bucket_S3"

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

for filename in os.listdir(local_path):

    print("Uploading:", filename)
    s3_client.upload_file(local_path + filename, bucket_name, prefix_key + filename)
```

Comment: Hello, do you have an answer for this question please ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this with command

```
aws s3 cp `your local folder` `s3://bucket`
```

Above command can also be run with python

```
import subprocess
local_folder = "/path/to/your/local/folder"
s3_bucket = "s3://bucket"

command = ["aws", "s3", "cp", local_folder, s3_bucket]


 try:
   subprocess.run(command, check=True)
   print("Files copied to S3 successfully!")
 except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
   print("Error:", e)
```

Comment: the idea is to automate the method, so I want it in the python code, not in CLI.

Comment: You can run above command via python, check my edited answer